# Celebrity prob1em recursive implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

"In a party of N people, only one person is known to everyone. Such a person may be present in the party, if yes, (s)he doesn’t know anyone in the party. We can only ask questions like “does A know B? “. Find the stranger (celebrity) in minimum number of questions."

How to do this recursive? Pseudocode will help...

Comment: Please provide minimal, verifiable and complete code that demonstrate the issue.

Comment: A knows B doesn't imply B knows A, because if B is the celebrity, B doesn't know anyone. There is also no rules stating that a non-celebrity must know someone, i.e. C doesn't know anybody but since not everybody knows C, C is not a celebrity. To locate the celebrity you pretty much need to ask everyone about everyone else. Is an algorithm for  "minimum number of questions" even possible?

Comment: Hint: "If does A know B?" gives you YES, then A cannot be a celebrity; if it gives you NO, then B cannot be a celebrity.  Now think about a device that takes 2 inputs and returns 1 output...  Can you connect some of these devices together in a useful way?  You'll need several rows of these devices, with a different number of devices in each row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.